# Oracle DB: how to store function result into variable inside procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

Good day. I have a function:

```
create function get_n(search tt.pp%type)
  return number
  is rc number;
begin
  select count(*)
  into rc
  from tt
  where tt.pp=search;

  return (rc);
end;
/
```

and i can get result as

```
variable qwe number;

begin
  select get_n('sample')
    into :qwe
    from dual;
end;

print qwe;
```

So, it's successfully works. But by parts: i can't exec line with `print` at execution of other (PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PRINT"...). And it's really strange.

I try to get result from function in anonymous block and print it:

```
declare
  qwe number;
begin
  select get_n('sample')
    into :qwe
    from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(qwe);
exception
  when others
    then dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
end;
/
```

And it's not print anything. Why?

Comment: And yep, i can just `:=` the value of the function, but why this doesn't works?

Comment: What's wrong with using the much simpler `qwe := get_n('sample')`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name all is great with this, just want to understand what is wrong in this case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem is `:`. Following code should work:

```
declare
  qwe number;
begin
  select get_n('sample')
    into qwe
    from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(qwe);
exception
  when others
    then dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
end;
/
```

`:` means variable that need to be binded not variable inside PL/SQL block. 
And in case of first block you're missing `/` after PL/SQL block what causes compiler reads `print` as part of PL/SQL not SQLplus script:

```
variable qwe number;

begin
  select get_n('sample')
    into :qwe
    from dual;
end;
/

print qwe;
```